# node.js page refresh calling resources twice?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a basic node.js setup, but I think I'm missing something.

My `main.js`:

```
var a = require('./another.js');

var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, 
    {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });

    response.write(a.saysomething('Hi there!') + '<br />');
    response.end();
}).listen(27182);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:27182/');
```

My `another.js`:

```
exports.saysomething = function (str) {
    console.log('in saysomething!');
    return str + ' hey there!';
}
```

The issue is that my console is outputting `in saysomething!` twice.  Am I missing something?  When I refresh the page, I expect only one `in saysomething!`.

Comment: Does your page contain anything other than text? Any images or anything with a SRC attribute in there?

Comment: No.  What I posted is legitimately all that I have.  My output is `Hi there! hey there!<br />`

Comment: Check your Chrome plugins - I had a sniffer plugin that was making a 2nd http request, every request!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your browser is likely trying to get favicon.ico in addition to the url you are hitting.  Try to just do the command on the command line: `curl http://127.0.0.1:27182/`

Also, you can add logging for `request.url`.  That will show you which urls are being requested.

Comment: Does it really re-request the entire page just for the favicon?

Comment: It re-requests /favicon.ico.  Your node code will respond to any url including /OHMYGODTHISISAURLTOO :)

Comment: Is there a way to ignore a route in node.js?  I know you can do it in asp.net mvc.

Comment: Look at express.js It has those kind of functions.  http://expressjs.com/guide.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to understand the problem.  This node server will track all the requests and show them to you on the browser in JSON.  Then you can hit F5 and watch the requests you are making.

```
    var http = require("http");

    var messages = [];

    http.createServer(function(request, response) {
      console.log("We got a hit @ " + new Date());          
      messages.push(request.url);
      messages.push(request.headers);

      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      for ( var i = 0; i < messages.length; ++i ) {
        response.write("\n\n" + JSON.stringify(messages[i]));
      }
      response.end();
    }).listen(8888);
```

PS: See also this duplicate for more info [nodejs - http.createServer seems to call twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961902/nodejs-http-createserver-seems-to-call-twice)

Comment: does this mean the response is also being sent out twice?

Comment: No.  This is basically like logging all requests, but you get to see the requests on the web page.  Maybe it is not very useful.