# callback on net.createServer() is called twice

Tags: node.js

I'm following the tutorial on [this tutorial](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001808/ch02.html#I_sect12_d1e1211).  Here's the code:

```
var net = require('net')

var chatServer = net.createServer()

chatServer.on('connection', function(client) {
client.write('Hi!\n');
client.write('Bye!\n');
console.log("got msg from http");  //added
client.end()
})

chatServer.listen(9000)
```

I placed a `console.log` between the `bye` and the `client.end()`

When I run it and hit port 9000, the `console.log` is outputed twice instead of once.

```
got msg from http
got msg from http
```

anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: Once for each request - note your browser may be requesting a favicon or similar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [nodejs - http.createServer seems to call twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961902/nodejs-http-createserver-seems-to-call-twice)

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I'm coming from the world of sugary asp.net to sugar-free zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using a browser to test your server. What you're seeing is two different incoming HTTP requests. Try the following code and you will likely see that there are two incoming HTTP requests:

```
var net = require('net')

var chatServer = net.createServer()

chatServer.on('connection', function(client) {
    client.write('Hi!\n');
    client.write('Bye!\n');

    console.log("got msg from http");  //added

    client.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('data: \n%s', data)
    });

    client.end()
})

chatServer.listen(9000)
```

The two requests should be  `GET /` and `GET /favicon.ico`, favicon.ico is the icon which is displayed on the browser tab and bookmarks etc.