# Nodejs http request console.log function prints twice

Tags: javascript, node.js

Whenever I make http requests to a server using node.js, the console.logs inside the http request function output twice. I set up a sever with the following code, and used localhost:8888 on firefox to make a request (localhost:8888):

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
function onRequest(request, response) {
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url, true).pathname;
    console.log("Your url pathname is " + pathname);
    response.write("Did you get your response?");
}
var new_server = http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
```

The console prints:

```
Your url pathname is /
Your url pathname is /favicon.ico
```

My questions are:

1. Why is the request sent twice?
2. Why is the pathname favicon.ico on the second request despite the fact that I did not specify anything after the socket number in the request url?
3. Is there any way you can fix these two issues?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [nodejs - http.createServer seems to call twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961902/nodejs-http-createserver-seems-to-call-twice)

Answer (score 5):

Obviously the request *isn't* sent twice, it's two requests.

It's the *browser* asking for the favicon. That's a thing browsers do.