# Node Http server - request received twice

Tags: node.js

I am learning `Node.js` and I have created this simple `http` server.

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    console.log('request accepted');
    res.end();
});

server.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Server listening on port #3000");
});
```

It is working fine but when I visit `http://localhost:3000/` the console logs `request accepted` thing twice. In short, if I'm understanding correctly, the request is received twice.

Is it a correct behavior or am I doing something wrong here?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [nodejs - http.createServer seems to call twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961902/nodejs-http-createserver-seems-to-call-twice)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your browser makes two HTTP requests.  One for the page at `/` and the other for `/favicon.ico`.

You can prove this by inspecting `req.url`.

Comment: Thanks, Brad :)
 Is there any way I can ignore the request for `favicon.ico`?

Comment: Check `req.url`. If it's `/favicon.ico` then end the request immediately with a 404.

Answer (score 0):

also check:

```
req.method
```

if it's a POST call may be preceeded by a preflight (OPTIONS method)