# nodejs - why does my async function run twice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am new to node.js and learning from tutorials online.
I was trying out the following piece of code :

```
var http = require("http");

// create a server
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    console.log("Received Request");
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'application/json'});
    res.end("{'status':'200', 'message':'Hello World'}");
    console.log("Response Sent");
}).listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
```

I did receive the correct response but in console the output was :

```
Received Request
Response Sent
Received Request
Response Sent
```

I wanted to know why was my code running twice ?? Am I making some mistake ?
Please help !!

Comment: Did you happen to refresh the page or visit it twice?

Comment: no, i just hit the url once from my browser address bar !!

Comment: This is almost certainly due to a browser making a second request for the favicon resource. Try `console.log("Received Request", req.url);`

Comment: Can you give an example how you send the request to the server? browser/curl/other

Comment: I think apsillers is correct, I dint think of that. @micmic I am using c9 for development, I wrote the code shown above, pressed the RUN button which deployed this code and then hit the url by copying it to the clipboard and pasting in browser address bar and then hitting enter, thats it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you access a url using the browser , the browser will send a request for the favicon, then send another request for the content, that's why you are seeing two requests !

Use PostMan and request the same url , you should see only one request.

Answer (score 3):

the best way to debug is to check the url

```
var http = require("http");

// create a server
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.url);//add this line, I hope it will help
    console.log("Received Request");
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'application/json'});
    res.end("{'status':'200', 'message':'Hello World'}");
    console.log("Response Sent");
}).listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
```

Also as Bassam Rubaye pointed out it might most likely due to favicon in your case

Comment: + for answers that teach you how to diagnose the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2):

No mistake--this is normal! Your browser makes multiple requests. There's a similar answer at [nodejs - http.createServer seems to call twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961902/nodejs-http-createserver-seems-to-call-twice).

Hope you're having fun learning node.js!