# Parsing query string problem using node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to extract my url id using the code under

```
var http =  require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');

var app = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    var _url = request.url;
    var queryData = url.parse(_url, true).query;
    console.log(queryData);

    if(_url == '/'){
        _url = '/index.html';
    }
    if(_url == '/favicon.ico'){
        return response.writeHead(404);
    }
    response.writeHead(200);

    response.end(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + _url));
});

app.listen(4040);
```

However, whether than having a result like`{id: 'HTML'}`the terminal keeps sending me this code whenever I click my web pages

```
[Object: null prototype] {}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nodejs - http.createServer seems to call twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961902/nodejs-http-createserver-seems-to-call-twice)

Comment: have you tried using `queryData = req.query`

Comment: You don't need to use use `url` to get to the `query` parameters. Use `req.query.id` to access the query parameter named `id`.

Comment: That is normal, browser makes two request (sometime more than twice)

Comment: To link directory you need to use `_url = '\\index.html';` instead if `_url = '/index.html';`

Comment: I thinks this have same problem with [parsing query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55350476/parsing-query-string-problem-using-node-js)