# How to avoid my route to call twice?in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

my route is calling twice,am using express, I have checked some link related to this

[node.js page refresh calling resources twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283801/node-js-page-refresh-calling-resources-twice?noredirect=1&lq=1)

so i have added console.log(req.url),

My output is

```
Hi..
/
Hi..
/
```

My code:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
console.log("Hi..")
console.log(req.url)
});
```

How do i solve this issue?

Comment: Try logging time, `console.log("We got a hit @ " + new Date());`

Comment: We got a hit @ Thu Jan 25 2018 11:54:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)      
We got a hit @ Thu Jan 25 2018 11:54:57 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Am getting in seconds delay .. so its running twice..How to avoid that

Comment: Your route is getting called twice when you do what?  What exactly did you do to cause it to get hit?  Did you go to some URL in a browser?  What URL?  Did you post a form via Javascript in a web page?  Is there any Javascript in your web page?

Comment: Am just loading login page. it contains captcha ,if i tried after clear history its working fine but after some time it calling twice